# Como faço para usar o GIT e sistema atualizar logo após o commit

Tags: php, linux, git

estou tendo uma dificuldade que irei exemplificar para vocês:
Estou começando a trabalhar com git agora e não sei muito sobre, mas comandos básicos e intermediários ta saindo. No meu caso, tenho um sistema todo em MVC em um servidor linux na rede e estou usando o git, porém eu gostaria de que quando terminasse o commit a modificação já ia pros arquivos do diretório em sí, tipo:

> var/www/html/Sistema

E o git ta assim:

> var/www/html/Sistema/.git/

Então... estou fazendo os commits e depois pegando lá no FTP mesmo e colando os nas pastas, no braço mesmo.

Gostaria de uma luz nisso. obrigado!

Comment: Quem é o admin do teu github? O Servidor configurado na conta do git? Através dele, pode-se fazer o `pull request` por lá

Answer (score 5):

Existe uma forma através do *git* , que é utilizando `hooks`. Em resumo você cria um repositório do tipo `bare`, que será responsável por receber os *commits* e copiá-los para a pasta de produção.

Nesse repositório do tipo `bare` que está deverá ser criado no servidor você cria um `hook` (Git hooks são scripts que rodam automaticamente cada vez que você realiza alguma ação em particular no repositório Git).
No seu caso, a ação será copiar os arquivos para produção toda vez que o repositório receber um *push*.

Este repositório `bare` deverá ser adicionado como `origin` da sua pasta de trabalho local. Assim você poderá enviar os dados via *push* para o seu servidor.

No linux é tranquilo de fazer, esse link poderá lhe ajudar.

[Deploy com Git — Configurando e executando um deploy automatizado](https://medium.com/@wesleysaraujo/deploy-com-git-configurando-e-executando-um-deploy-automatizado-156e3e1bc374)

Comment: Recomendo fortemente corrigir os desvios de português e também dar uma ênfase nos termos estrangeiros. Ou por a formatação de código _inline_ em conceitos do git, como `hook` ou _bare_

Comment: Também seria uma resposta muito mais completa se você colocasse como fazer um _hook_ no git, que eu particularmente só sei que existe, não sei fazer um. A ideia é que as respostas fiquem completas, fazendo o SOpt ser uma referência de material sobre programação, extremamente condensado e de ótima qualidade

Comment: Nossa! muito bom! consegui fazer isso seguindo os passos do site que você passou. Obrigado mesmo! usarei para todos os meus projetos particulares.